# How to disable vscode autocomplete when using a dot after an integer in python?

Tags: python, autocomplete, visual-studio-code

When typing an integer followed by a dot, e.g. `2.` in a python file, autocomplete suggest "and, if, or" and some other words:
[image]

How can I disable this? Trying `"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false` as suggested in some JS answers did not work.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. There's no indication of it being possible [in the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense), though `editor.quickSuggestions": {"other": false}` may work.

Comment: @Glazbee Do you know what is the reason for suggesting such keywords after a dot?

Comment: I do not unfortunately. It doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0):

It's because Jedi considers those reasonable suggestions. If you switch to our language server by setting `"python.jediEnabled": false` then you won't get those suggestions.